# Display gallery photos and videos in a gridview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to load users gallery photos and videos. In this screen there will be all users photos and videos just like in the gallery. I don't want to have photos first and videos after all the photos but I just want in order like in the gallery. I don't to pick the videos and photos I just want a screen where the users can see their gallery of photos and videos. Display all of these in a grid view with circular borders, the videos will be in a stack where there will be a little button in the middle so I can play the video on the next screen.

This is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work since I am getting this error:
Unhandled Exception: PathNotFoundException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.syn_ios_android/files/DCIM/' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Any help would be appreciated

```
class GalleryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GalleryScreenState createState() => _GalleryScreenState();
}

class _GalleryScreenState extends State<GalleryScreen> {
  List<File> _imageFiles = [];
  List<File> _videoFiles = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadMediaFiles();
  }

  Future<void> _loadMediaFiles() async {
    final externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final dcimDir = Directory('${externalDir.path}/DCIM');
    final cameraDir = Directory('${dcimDir.path}/Camera');
    final imageFiles = cameraDir
        .listSync()
        .where((file) =>
            file is File &&
            file.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpg') ||
            file.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.png'))
        .cast<File>()
        .toList();
    final videoFiles = cameraDir
        .listSync()
        .where((file) =>
            file is File &&
            file.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.mp4') ||
            file.path.toLowerCase().endsWith('.mov'))
        .cast<File>()
        .toList();
    setState(() {
      _imageFiles = imageFiles;
      _videoFiles = videoFiles;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Gallery'),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: _imageFiles.length + _videoFiles.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4,
          mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (index < _imageFiles.length) {
            return Image.file(
              _imageFiles[index],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            );
          } else {
            final int videoIndex = index - _imageFiles.length;
            final videoPlayerController =
                VideoPlayerController.file(_videoFiles[videoIndex]);
            return AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: [
                  VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController),
                  Center(
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        videoPlayerController.play();
                      },
                      child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can be shown "video & photos" based on created date ordering format to show the same as in the gallery.

Comment: @NitinGadhiya I am having problems displaying the videos & photos from the gallery at the first place.